# How to calculate average of count per day in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, average, aggregate-functions

I have a table called SDON, and a query that counts the total number of pallets on each date of import. I wish to group these together and average the counts per month.

My count query:

```
SELECT COUNT(`storage unit`) AS `Pallets`, `import_date` 
FROM `SDON` 
GROUP BY `import_date`
```

[image: query result]

I wish for the following:

[image: Average Pallets | Import Month 18500]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group the results of your original query by year and month of the date:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM import_date) AS import_month
     , AVG(day_total) AS average_per_day
FROM (
    SELECT import_date
         , COUNT(`storage unit`) AS day_total
    FROM sdon
    GROUP BY import_date
) AS x
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM import_date)
```

Converting a number such as `202207` to `2022-07` is trivial.

Comment: OP wanted the avg by month I think :)

Comment: Yes an extra group by is needed. I will update.

Comment: I get the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*) AS `Average Pallets`,
from `SDON`
group by extract(YEAR from `import_da...' at line 1

Comment: See revised answer. The subquery needs an `as whatever` alias.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  AVG(Pallets) AS AveragePallets,
        DATE_FORMAT(import_date, '%b-%y') AS ImportMonth
    FROM sdon
    GROUP BY LEFT(import_date, 7)
    ORDER BY LEFT(import_date, 7);
```

(I don't see any need for a subquery.)